# IntelliJ Can't use Subversion command line client : svn

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5CyN.png)

What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: First, please include the actual text of the error so we don't have to go clicking looking for what the problem is. Second, have you tried what the error message is telling you to try, and if so, why didn't it work? Third (or perhaps even first), have you actually installed `svn`?

Comment: "enter image description here" links to images are not recommended in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

The `Can't use Subversion command line client: svn` message appears when the client specified in settings cannot be started.

Make sure you have command line svn client installed and either specify an explicit path to it in settings or ensure svn executable is on the PATH and simple `svn` command works when called from the command line